# website is stop responding after every two days which is developed in SPRING

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I have developed website using SPRING framework and used C3po connection pooling also used Spring security, but when i deployed it on tomcat server 
it works fine for two days but after two days it automaticaly stop responding,

I have checked memory leak if any but not found anything and also not get any log of memmory leak in log files,
Also check memory after every hours and its working fine.
Also my website users are average 1000. and session timeout is 8 hours, also given 2GB RAM for tomcat instance.

So Please help me out in this.

Comment: Do you have log enabled for tomcat as well?

Comment: Check the connection and connection pool. (maybe all connections are blocked)

Comment: Yes tomcat log is enable,

Comment: Is it stopping after almost the same amount of time? Are you running any scheduling type of tasks?

Comment: Almost after two days and I am not running any schedule type tasks.

Comment: Did you try deploying it on another application server (instead of Tomcat)? I assume that whenever your application stops responding, you're re-deploying it again on Tomcat?